# OpenCV for iOS framework error "Base.hpp" header must be compiled as C++

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

As the title says, I'm getting "XXX.hpp" header must be compiled as C++" whenever I try to #import an .hpp file.

Any tips for resolving this issue?

Ive tried numerous build settings configurations including setting a -lc++ linker flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I have fixed my compilation issue by renaming my Objective-C .m file to .mm. This makes sense as I'm importing a c++ header file.

This other answer helped me with this question:
[Objective-C++ compilation errors due to Xcode not respecting file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982091/objective-c-compilation-errors-due-to-xcode-not-respecting-file-type)